# have onTouchEvent only work on bottom half go the screen

Tags: java, android

I'd like to have two onTouchEvents on my app. One event would only work on the top half of the screen and the other event would only work on the bottom half of the screen. Is this possible?

```
//top
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 
    this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    // my logic
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

//bottom
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 
    this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    // my logic
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: As long as the top and bottom half have their own views to recognize the touch events separately, then yes it's possible.

Comment: but how do you set each touch event to a view?

Comment: I provided an example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the only provided solutions require you to use multiple Views, I figured I would provide one for a single View that encompasses the entire screen:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getY() < activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / 2){
         //top
    }
    else{
         //bottom
    }
    return true; //handle the touch
}
```

This was me just assuming you were only using a single View...

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
topLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.topLayout);
bottomLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottomLayout);

topLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "top was touched");
        return false;
    }
});

bottomLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "bottom was touched");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Or you could move those anonymous classes to their own respective classes and use them:

```
topLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.topLayout);
bottomLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottomLayout);

topLayout.setOnTouchListener(new TopOnTouchListener());
bottomLayout.setOnTouchListener(new BottomOnTouchListener());
```

This is assuming you have *some* view that spans the top and bottom of your layout. In the above example I'm using two `LinearLayout`s to do so, but feel free to choose your own.